# Matplotlib GUI different 2.7 and 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

I recently 'downgraded' my python environment from 3.5.2 to 2.7.12 to match the cluster I'm using for work. I still have the same version of Matplotlib (2.2.2) but now when I show the graphs I no longer have the same GUI controls to zoom etc.

Is this standard or could it be due to me also moving from using anaconda to self-managed virtual environments at the same time?

I miss my zoom tool please help!

Comment: In general one would expect the matplotlib GUI to look the same in python 3 and python 2. It will rather depend on which backend is used - however all interactive backends should also give you similar toolbars. Check which backend you are using, possibly use a different one to check, also maybe provide a screenshot here and the more information available on your "self-managed" ve there are, the easier for anyone to spot the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ahh okay I think it must be that PyQt5 doesn't support 2.7

Comment: Not sure what that means. If PyQt5 cannot be run on py2, you should not get any GUI using the "PyQt5Agg" backend, instead of just the toolbar missing. If however you are not using "PyQt5", it cannot be an issue with "PyQt5" at all.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It turns out it was that it was using tkagg rather than qt4agg (which should be the default?) as the backend. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction

Comment: The "TkAgg" also has a toolbar.